# Find index of words in matched text

Tags: java, matcher

I'm using `Matcher` to find a phrase in a sentence, but I want to also find the index of each word in the phrase found. What I mean by this is imagine a sentence is indexed by each word:

```
This is my wonderful sentence
0    1  2  3         4
```

They would be indexed as above. However, I need to find only the phrase itself and not single words from the phrase elsewhere in the sentence.

```
I know this sentence repeats but you know that it doesn't
0 1    2    3        4       5   6   7    8    9  10
```

If I match the phrase `but you know` I then want to get the index of the words matched, but I don't want to return index 1 for the word `know` near the beginning, I only want to return 5, 6 and 7. I can't think of any good way to do this after I match the phrase with this code:

```
String line = "I know this sentence repeats but you know that it doesn't";

final Matcher match = Pattern.compile("but you know").matcher(line);
if (match.find()) 
    System.out.println(match.group(0));
```

So to be clear, I then want the index numbers 5, 6 and 7 from this matched phrase, in an array or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to do it.

- find the index of the phrase and get the substring of the sentence up to that point.
- then count the words in the substring using split. The length of the array will be the starting index in the first word of the phrase unless the `indexOfPhrase == 0`.  Then it will be 0.
- Then split the phrase to get each word, incrementing the previous word index of the initial substring.

```
String sentence =
        "I know this sentence repeats but you know that it doesn't";

String phrase = "but you know";

int indexOfPhrase = sentence.indexOf(phrase);

String[] temp = sentence.substring(0, indexOfPhrase).trim().split("\\s+");
int firstIndex = indexOfPhrase == 0 ? 0 : temp.length;

int start = firstIndex;
for (String word : phrase.split("\\s+")) {
    System.out.printf("%8s : %d%n", word,start++);
}
```

Prints

```
     but : 5
     you : 6
    know : 7
```

to put the values in an array you can do the following:

```
int[] indices = new int[phrase.split("\\s+").length]; 
Arrays.setAll(indices, i-> firstIndex+i);
```

Comment: Nice, a clever way of doing it. There should be no need for a safety check since I'd only run this code if the phrase was matched using my code above. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hmm it actually doesn't work correctly if the phrase is right at the beginning. Like in your example if the phrase is "I know this" it will get the first index as 1 rather than 0..So "know this sentence" returns 1,2,3, as does "I know this"....?

Comment: @hasen  Mea Culpa.  I hadn't considered that if the index of the phrase is 0 it will still return an array of length 1 instead of 0.  I believe I fixed it.  I tried front end end border cases.

Comment: Yes that's similar to how I fixed it, that's the only way I think. I felt you should fix it first before I accepted it since it should be fully working code of course. Thanks again for your help. My solution was just to add `if (sentence.indexOf(phrase) == 0) firstIndex = 0;` after your original code.