# find index of word in sentence with information from phrase

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, nlp, nltk

I need the index of `word` in `sentence`. But sometimes there are repetitions of the words. The `phrase` information would then be helpful. Or the previous or next row in the `word` column.

Basically, I just need to identify the word in the utterance, e.g. if the `word` is 'seaside', I want to know which 'seaside' it is in the sentence. I have extra information from the `phrase` that can help with this identification. The order of their appearance in the dataframe can also help.

What I have right now is this:

| file_id | phrase | word | sentence | word_indices |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | I am | I | I am a happy bird. I sing every day. I eat worms. | [0, 5, 9] |
| B | the seaside is | the | she is by the seaside. The seaside is packed. | [3, 5] |
| B | the seaside is | seaside | she is by the seaside. The seaside is packed. | [4, 6] |
| B | the seaside is | is | she is by the seaside. The seaside is packed. | [1, 7] |
| C | nobody knows | nobody | nobody knows what is going on. She can find nobody | [0, 9] |
| C | find nobody | nobody | nobody knows what is going on. She can find nobody | [0, 9] |
| D | it is such a sunny day | sunny | it is such a sunny day ah I am so happy when it's sunny such a sunny day is the best | [4, 13, 16] |

But what I want to get is what is in the `target` column.

| file_id | phrase | word | sentence | word_indices | target |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | I am | I | I am a happy bird. I sing every day. I eat worms. | [0, 5, 9] | [0] |
| B | the seaside is | the | she is by the seaside. The seaside is packed. | [3, 5] | [5] |
| B | the seaside is | seaside | she is by the seaside. The seaside is packed. | [4, 6] | [6] |
| B | the seaside is | is | she is by the seaside. The seaside is packed. | [1, 7] | [7] |
| C | nobody knows | nobody | nobody knows what is going on. She can find nobody | [0, 9] | [0] |
| C | find nobody | nobody | nobody knows what is going on. She can find nobody | [0, 9] | [9] |
| D | it is such a sunny day | sunny | it is such a sunny day ah I am so happy when it's sunny such a sunny day is the best | [4, 13, 16] | [4] |

I found a similar question here: [Find index of words in matched text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68915716/find-index-of-words-in-matched-text)
But unfortunately, this is in java and I need an answer using python.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you give a more precise definition? I assume, that if the `word` is not unique in the sentence, the algorithm shall lookup the `phrase` term and return the index of the word with the first occurrence of the phrase,  right? What shall happen if the `phrase` appears multiple times? What shall happen if the `word` appears multiple times but the `phrase` does not appear?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes, the questions you asked are also my questions. Basically, I just need to identify the word in the utterance, e.g. if the `word` is 'seaside', I want to know which 'seaside' it is in the sentence. I have extra information from the `phrase` that can help with this identification. The order of their appearance in the dataframe can also help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would break it down into two steps. Find the number of words leading up to the phrase in the sentence and then the word index number of the word in the phrase: Something like below:

```
def get_index_of_word_in_sentence(word, phrase, sentence):
    index1 = sentence.index(phrase)
    word_num1 = len(sentence[:index1].split())
    word_num2 = phrase.split().index(word)
    return word_num1 + word_num2

df["target"] = df.apply(lambda x: get_index_of_word_in_sentence(x["word"], x["phrase"], x["sentence"]), axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It seems this is counting the index of strings? I got the following  results:[0, 23, 27, 35, 0, 44, 13]. It doesn't seem to be what I needed...

Comment: Aaaah yes, i misread the question. I have amended my answer.

Comment: That worked! Thanks!

Comment: @SuperDuperMario , could you please let me know how you get the indices of the word?

Comment: @DanielWyatt How can I modify your function to get the word indices if I don't have them (basically, I need to fill out the column word_indices)? Thank you!!

Comment: @Mary Modify the function to return something like `[index for index, string in enumerate(sentence.split()) if string == word]` and then do `df["target"] = df.apply(lambda x: get_index_of_word_in_sentence(x["word"], x["sentence"]), axis=1)`